# javascript: setting field value and submitting the form

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to set the value of a hidden field and then submit the form with js.

Here's my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function doSubmit(formid,fieldid,action) {
    var frm=getElementbyId(formid);
    var fld=getElementbyId(fieldid);
    fld.value = action;     
    frm.submit();
}
//-->
</script>
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<form name="mainform" id="mainform" method="post">
    <a href="#" onclick="doSubmit('mainform','dothis','send')">send</a>
    <input name="dothis" id="dothis" type="hidden" value="nothing" />
</form>
```

Result: nothing happens.

When I do `<a href="#" onclick="document.mainform.submit()"> ...` the form is submitted (but, of course, the value in `dothis`not set.

How to do this?

Comment: what is getElementById??? Is it your custom function?? If not should be document.getElementById(formid)

Comment: @ZKK: changed it, still nothing happens...

Comment: try my solution. change href to href="javascript:void(0)". I think your form is not submitting. Its only sending you to a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is getElementById??? Is it your custom function?? Also I think your form is not submitted. Its just calling the href="#" which is the same link. 
set the href value to

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Js function :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function doSubmit(formid, fieldid, action) {
        var frm = document.getElementById(formid);
        var fld = document.getElementById(fieldid);
        fld.value = action;
        frm.submit();
    }
    //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
document.getElementById
```

not

```
getElementbyId (missing capital B)
```